# Hibernate stores data as serialized in a single row instead of in sepater rows

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate and I am stuck with annotations. I have a POJO Item:

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    protected Integer id;

    @Column
    protected State state;

    @ElementCollection
    protected Map<Locale, ItemBody> localization = new EnumMap<Locale, T>(Locale.class);

    ...

}
```

Locale is an enum of four items:

```
public enum Locale {
    cs, en, de, fr, es
}
```

ItemBody:

```
public class ItemBody implements Serializable {

    @Column(length = 256)
    protected String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    protected String description;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    protected String excerpt;

    ...
}
```

I use it as a key to attach translations of texts for Item.

Ideally, Hibernate would generate two classes:

```
 Item (id, state)
 ItemBody (item_id, localization_KEY, name, description, excerpt)
```

where in item_id and localization_KEY form together primary key.

What happens is that Hibernate generates:

```
 Item (id, state)
 ItemBody (item_id, localization, localization_KEY)
```

where localization is of type Bytea and is a serialization of all rows in ItemBody, instead of listing all the rows. I will appreciate any suggestion for what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must annotate ItemBody with `@Embeddable`. Otherwise, Hibernate treats it as a serializable object.

Comment: When I annotate the ItemBody class with Embeddable, I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException (https://gist.github.com/1657644). I can confirm, it is caused by the localization variable of Item - the exception is not thrown.

Comment: Try adding `@CollectionTable(name="ItemBody0", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="item_id"))
   @Column(name="locale")` to the `localization` field.

Comment: Try debugging the class causing the exception to see what it expects. I have no other idea.